# Issue with Codeigniter url

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and I'm going through the tutorials. I created a new controller and when I try to create a link as shown below its throws an error.

```
<p><a href="dashboard">Dashboard</a></p>
```

However when I change the link as shown below everything works fine.

```
<p><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard">Dashboard</a></p>
```

Is this how things work in Codeigniter? Is there a way I can build links without using base_url everytime?

P.S. For now I don't care about the index.php in the link.

Comment: What's "the error" it throws? Does the page `dashboard` exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like in your head area use base https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

```
<head>
   <base href="<?php echo base_url();?>">
</head>
```

Then you should be able to use like

```
<p><a href="dashboard">Dashboard</a></p>
```

> Make sure you have set your base url like below and end with `/`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

Or

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/;
```

And autoload the url helper config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

> Tip: Make sure your controller files start with first letter only uppercase same applies for class name

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Example:

Filename: Dashboard.php

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this is the right way? Including base tag in <head> is important?

Comment: I would think so by the https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp example You do not need `target="_blank"` in base tag though There are many was to do it but this is way I would do it but this was just to give you idea.

Comment: Thank you very much. For now I will stick to this.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, issue is because of using relative URLs.
For example, those won't work when you are using deeper level URI segments.
Consider next few examples:

If base of your application is `http://www.example.com/` which you should set in config file too by setting `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';`, when you are on that URL with your browser, and when you click on some relative URL you will be pointed/redirected to URL that is current URL appended by relative link.

```
http://www.example.com/ => http://www.example.com/dashboard
```

but if you are in some deeper segment, let's say `http://www.example.com/index/15`, `dashboard` will be extending that one although you would like it points to `http://www.example.com/dashboard`

```
http://www.example.com/index/15 => http://www.example.com/index/15/dashboard
```

As other said, you should set and use `base_url()` CodeIgniter inbuilt function (use appendix as parameter of function `base_url('dashboard')` ).
If you would like to use it without `base_url('some-page')` function, you should use either absolute URL either relative to server route one. 
The latter one would look like as with prepended slash that is telling web server to use root location defined in `.htacces` file or virtual host environment settings `/dashboard`. In your former example

```
<p><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></p>
```

should work just well. 
If it is not working you need to set RewriteBase attribute in .htaccess file.
Check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls#comment-14197563) here and check some articles that describe differences, pro and cons between relative and absolute URLs